# Search Bar up, yet cannot search.

Tags: android

Now I have this search bar up with code below.

Link : http://pastebin.com/6vSBR8iX

How do I let it become the type of search window like the market has?

This is the Android manifest I have.

Link : http://pastebin.com/ue6NSTCr

Someone please help me out with this. I have tried

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.search);

// Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
  doMySearch(query);
     }
}
```

But could not get the search up.

Comment: Anyone can suggest how to work out something like androidmarket's search bar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the guide here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#PerformingSearch

If you have created Activity and Action Bar Widget, I hope you did not forget to add:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And to clarify your question, could you please post more info?

Cheers!